# Error "500 behavior::tabstate not found." when trying to access SP Page Builder

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I am currently using Joomla 4.0.0 Beta 6 with Helix Ultimate 2.0.0 Alpha 3 and PHP 7.2. My website runs on LiteSpeed Web Server, NOT Apache.

When I go to The Joomla administrator panel > SP Page Builder > Pages, I get the following error:
*

```
"An error has occurred.
500 behavior::tabstate not found."
```

Here is what I got in the logs file:

*CRITICAL ..... error Uncaught Throwable of type InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "behavior::tabstate not found.". Stack trace: #0 ~/public_html/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/sppagebuilder.php(18): Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::_('jhtml.behavior....')*

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Download the Helix Ultimate Quickstart Package at https://www.joomshaper.com/downloads/template/helixultimate and upload it to your website's public_html folder.
2. Unzip the package file.
3. Go to [www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php](http://www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php) and follow the installation procedures.
4. Upgrade Helix Ultimate to 2.0.0 Alpha 3 (The download link: https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.3) and Joomla! to 4.0.0 Beta 6.

Comment: Please post all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: may I suggest you bring this up with the Helix developers? it's alpha. And you should definitely be using php7.4 or newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the above problem solved after using Helix Ultimate 2 Beta 2 Quickstart Package (https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/download/v2.0.0-beta.2/helixultimate_2_beta2_quickstart.zip).

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Download the Helix Ultimate Quickstart Package at https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.2 and upload it to your website's public_html folder.
2. Unzip the package file.
3. Go to [www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php](http://www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php) and follow the installation procedures.
4. Upgrade your site to Joomla 4 Beta 7.